# Erro: “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction” MySql

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando Alimentar uma tabela no mysql com informações de uma outra tabela, mas quando vou dar o update me retorna esse erro:

> Erro: “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction”.

O código do update é o seguinte.

```
 UPDATE mis.basecelmax tbl
SET tbl.obs =
  (SELECT max(tmp.obs)
   FROM mis.basetemp tmp
   WHERE tmp.id = tbl.id)
WHERE tbl.obs IS NULL
  AND tbl.id > 0
```

Isso acontece independente da quantidade de registros que tento atualizar.

Comment: Complicado analisar somente com essas informações. Quantos registros são alterados nesse `update`?

Comment: Na tabela tenho cerca de 23k registros para alteração, mas com o erro não da uptade em nenhum.

Comment: Samuel como é sua hospedagem? Pode ser o servidor que não suporta essa `query`.

Comment: No caso o servidor suporta sim a query Moises, já consegui executar esse update ontem em testes, mas hoje tentando executar com o histórico não foi.

Comment: @SamuelAlves no seu teste tinha a mesma quantidade de registros?

Comment: Não, testei com poucos registros, hoje tentei com 23k, e tive esse erro. Tentei retornar para a pouca quantia dos testes e o erro persistiu.

Comment: Mesmo assim era bom verificar com seu servidor. Esse erro é comum de problemas de infra.